# $ya^n - by = 1$ has one solution, then $xa-bx = 1$ also has one solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a ring and $a,b \in R, n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $b^2 = b$ and the equation $ya^n - by = 1$ has one solution.
>
> Prove that the equation $xa - bx = 1$ also has one solution.

Let $y$ be the solution of the equation $ya^n - by = 1$.

By multiplying the equation $ya^n - by = 1$ with $b$ we obtain: $$bya^n - by = b \iff bya^n - ya^n = b-1 \iff (b-1)ya^n = b-1.$$

If $(b-1)$ is inverible, then $ya^n = 1$, so both $y$ and $a^n$ are invertible.

But $ya^n - by = 1 \iff by=0 \implies b = 0$.

This means that the equation $xa - bx = 1$ has the solution $x = ya^{n-1}$.

I just don't know how to proceed if $(b-1)$ is not invertible.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a silly question. Does "has one solution" mean "is solvable" or "has exactly one solution"?

Comment: Exactly one solution.

Comment: You have a few hidden mistakes in your argument, e.g. $ya^n=1$ wouldn't imply that any of $y$ or $a^n$ are invertible, only that $y$ would have a right inverse, and $a^n$ would have a left inverse. In a noncommutative ring, these might not be unique (just think about $2\times2$ matrices).

In a general ring we don't have the implication $\ by=0\implies b=0,\,$ knowing $y\ne0$
It just these that these are (left/right) *zero divisors*.

And, well, in the given situation, $\ b-1$ will be left invertible only if $b=0$, because $(b-1)b=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $R$ as a module over the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}[A,B]/(B^2-B)$ where the action is defined by
$$\begin{align}
Az&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}az\\
Bz&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}zb\text{.}
\end{align}$$
In this commutative ring, if $n\geq 2$ then
$$\begin{split}A^n-B&=A^n-B^n\\
&=(A-B)h_{n-1}(A,B)\\
&=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+B h_{n-2}(A,1))
\end{split}$$
where $h_{i}$ is the complete symmetric polynomial of degree $i$ in two variables
$$h_{i}(t,u)=t^i +t^{i-1}u+\cdots + u^i\text{.}$$
Consequently, if $y$ is a solution of $(A^n-B)y=1$ then $x=h_{n-1}(A,B)y$ is a solution to $(A-B)x=1$.

On the other hand, let $x$,$x'$ satisfy $(A-B)x=1$, $(A-B)x'=1$. Write $\Delta x$ for their difference: we have $(A-B)\Delta x=0$. But from above, we have
$$A^n-B=h_{n-1}(A,B)(A-B)$$
so that 
$$(A^n-B)\Delta x =h_{n-1}(A,B)(A-B)\Delta x =0$$

which implies that $(A^n-B)(y+\Delta x)=1$ whenever $(A^n-B)y=1$. But then $y=y+\Delta x$ by uniqueness, whence $\Delta x=0$, i.e., $x=x'$.

Comment: Hmmm.. nice approach. The actions of $A,B$ on $R$ commute. In elementary terms, for $n=2$, we have:
$$(A-B)(A+B)y=(A-B)\underbrace{(ya+by)}_x=(ya^2+bya\ -\ bya - b^2y)=ya^2-by$$